# MySQL & PHP Get Num of Records for Each Type

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL database table which holds 6 types of records I need to get the total number of records for each of the types and then create a variable for each one of the results so for example

wt = 3
spv = 33
shw = 78

and so on..

I have written this code

```
$tquery = "SELECT equipment, COUNT(id) AS num FROM contract GROUP BY equipment"; 
$tresult = mysql_query($tquery) or die(mysql_error());
while($trow = mysql_fetch_array($tresult)){
echo "There are ". $trow['COUNT(id)'] ." ". $trow['equipment'] ." items.";
echo "<br />";
}
```

The reason for needing a variable for each type is that I need to work out a percentage value to show this data in a chart, I have written this code and it works fine as long as I have the correct data from the table.

Any help would be awesome thanks

Comment: Creating variables in a *dynamic way* is not a good idea. If you really want to do it, you should read about [Variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php), though I would advise you to use an array instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, where you're referencing `$trow['COUNT(id)']`, this is incorrect; it should be coming back to you with the name `num` (as defined in your SQL query), so you should actually be using `$trow['num']`.

Now to store your totals:

Create an array to contain your totals. Lets call it `$total`. Define it as an empty array outside the `while` loop:

```
$total = array();
```

Then inside the loop, assign a new element for the `$total` array containing the equipment type as the key, and the count as the value:

```
$total[$trow['equipment']] = $trow['num'];
```

When the loop is finished, you should then have an array containing all the totals, which you can perform calculations on. PHP provides you with the `array_sum()` and `count()` functions (among plenty of other handy functions) which should be enough to get you started with working out averages and percentages.

hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like :

```
$tquery = "SELECT equipment, COUNT(id) AS num FROM contract GROUP BY equipment";
$tresult = mysql_query($tquery) or die(mysql_error());
while ($tabl = mysql_fetch_array($tresult)){
       echo "There are " . $tabl['num'] . " of " . $tabl['equipment'] . ".<br />";
}
```

Comment: Why have you removed his `while` loop? Surely the way you've written it means the code will loop through each field in the first record rather than looping through each record as intended?

Comment: Hmm yes it seems I misunderstood something in the question :p I will edit it !